# R: Draw a random number according to calculated h(x) and f(x)

Tags: r

I've calculated relative frequency of each class h(x) and cumulative relative frequency f(x) as it is shown:
[image]

### The 8 classes are intervals for x values. And the ecdf I think is like [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1kPY.jpg). So how can I achieve this plot in R and how can I draw a random number?

Comment: What do you mean by "function"? You can use `sample(unique(df$Class), 1, prob = df$h)` to draw one random `Class` with the probabilities provided by the vector `h`.

Comment: I meant a actual formula e.g. h(x) = 3x^2. I am completely beginner in R and maybe my first idea was wrong. How would you do it if you have the table I uploaded?

Comment: Note that only three of your Classes have been observed, so the other classes will never be drawn randomly if you use LAP's approach (which I think is the correct approach)

Comment: Can you please see the new figure i uploaded? Hope this helps me explain what i need. If i can draw a random number from Class with the cumulative paobabilities provided by f(x), then all the classes can be possibly drawn right? No class will be missing. But I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, first to discuss your latest comment and edit:

Considering the data you provided and the ECDF you drew from hand, I can't see how using cumulative probabilities to sample your random number makes any sense. Only three of your categories have observations, so drawing a random number from this distribution will not include any empty categories. The following answer will nonetheless use cumulative probabilities to draw your random number, as per your request.

On to a possible answer based on this premise:

You can draw your ECDF using the `plot.ecdf()` function from the `stats` package, which should come with your base installation of `R`. I'm gonna take the time to recreate your data myself, but for possible further questions you post on Stackoverflow, please use the `dput()` function to provide your data for us to use.

```
df <- data.frame("class" = 1:8, "lower_bound" = c(.33, .375, .4166667, .4583333, .5, .5416667, .5833333, .625),
                 "upper_bound" = c(.375, .4166667, .4583333, .5, .5416667, .5833333, .625, .6666667),
                 "n" = c(5, 0, 0, 49, 0, 0, 0, 9))
df$h <- df$n/sum(df$n)
df$f <- cumsum(df$h)

> df
  class lower_bound upper_bound  n          h          f
1     1   0.3300000   0.3750000  5 0.07936508 0.07936508
2     2   0.3750000   0.4166667  0 0.00000000 0.07936508
3     3   0.4166667   0.4583333  0 0.00000000 0.07936508
4     4   0.4583333   0.5000000 49 0.77777778 0.85714286
5     5   0.5000000   0.5416667  0 0.00000000 0.85714286
6     6   0.5416667   0.5833333  0 0.00000000 0.85714286
7     7   0.5833333   0.6250000  0 0.00000000 0.85714286
8     8   0.6250000   0.6666667  9 0.14285714 1.00000000
```

To plot the empirical cumulative distribution function, we can use

```
plot.ecdf(df$f)
```

[image: ECDF-Plot]

Now, I assume you want to draw a random number from within the bounds (defined by `df$lower_bound` and `df$upper_bound`) of the corresponding class (`df$class`), based on the cumulative distribution (`df$f`).

We can do this with a combination of `sample()` and `runif()`. First we draw a random class with

```
rndclass <- sample(unique(df$class), 1, prob = df$f)

> rndclass
[1] 7
```

Then we generate a random number from within the interval of the randomly chosen class:

```
rndvalue <- runif(1, df$lower_bound[df$class == rndclass], df$upper_bound[df$class == rndclass])

> rndvalue
[1] 0.6000935
```

If you only wanted to draw a random class, just disregard the last step. If you decide to rather use the relative distribution, just insert `df$h` for `df$f`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much LAP for your time and I am sorry for the unusable data. Will use dput() in the future!

Comment: Glad to help. Be aware that when using cumulative probabilities, category 8 has the highest chance to be chosen by `sample()`. I would definitely recommend to either use the "real" probabilities (`df$h`) or to generate new probabilities by distributing the ones in `df$h` between the others in accordance to the cumulative probs. Either way, have fun learning `R` :)